# Pivot table with rolling average

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I try to create a pivot table to get a time series with a rolling average of two days over time. For that, I am using the pivot_table() with aggfunc='mean' but so far I was only able to create a mean for each day, without taking the previous day also into account. This would be a simple example data.frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Date':['2021-01-01', '2021-01-01', '2021-01-01', '2021-01-02', '2021-01-02', '2021-01-02', '2021-01-02', '2021-01-03', '2021-01-03', '2021-01-03'],
    'Name':['Tim', 'Tim', 'Ben', 'Leo', 'Tim', 'Ben', 'Leo', 'Leo', 'Ben', 'Tim'], 
    'Ratings':[9.0, 8.0, 5.0, 3.0, 'NaN', 'NaN', 6, 5, 3, 5]})
```

This is what I tried, but I don't know how to incorporate a rolling window of 2, to also consider the previous day for the mean of the rating.

```
df.pivot_table(
        values='Ratings', index='Date', columns='Name',
        fill_value=0, aggfunc='mean')
```

This would be what I try to achieve.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Date':['2021-01-01', '2021-01-02', '2021-01-03'],
    'Tim':[8.5, 8.5, 5], 
    'Ben':[5, 5, 3],
    'Leo':['NaN', 4.5, 4.66],})
```

Thank you very much for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case

```
out = df.pivot_table(
    values='Ratings', index='Date', columns='Name',
     aggfunc='mean').ffill(limit=1)
Name        Ben  Leo  Tim
Date                     
2021-01-01  5.0  NaN  8.5
2021-01-02  5.0  4.5  8.5
2021-01-03  3.0  5.0  5.0
```

Comment: Great thanks a lot for your answer. How would I need to change it in order to calculate the average on each day also includes the values from the previous day (with rolling window of two)?